# Create new variable in R based on existing variable

Tags: r

I have a new problem with R - I am currently teaching myself how to use it for my bachelor thesis in Psychology, so bear with me if my questions are really naive.

Right now I am trying to create a new variable based on an already existing one. The existing one has 4 different expressions: T1, T2, T3 and T4. They may look something like this:

```
subject       scenario
1             T1
2             T3
3             T3
4             T2
5             T2
6             T4
```

The new variable I am trying to create should give the following values: For `T1` and `T2`the new variable should be `personal` and for `T3`and `T4`it should be `impersonal`.
The output data should therefore look like this:

```
subject      scenario    personal force
1            T1          personal
2            T3          impersonal
3            T3          impersonal
4            T2          personal
5            T2          personal
6            T4          impersonal
```

What code can I create to do this?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!:)

Comment: TRY: pd %>% mutate(personal_force = ifelse(scenario %in% c('T1','T2'), 'personal', 'impersonal'))           where 'pd' is your dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option can be:

```
#Code
df$NewVar <- ifelse(df$scenario %in% c('T1','T2'),'personal','impersonal')
```

Another option with indexing (if you only want the new variable with the classes `personal/impersonal`):

```
#Code 2
df$NewVar <- 'impersonal'
df$NewVar[df$scenario %in% c('T1','T2')] <- 'personal'
```

The output in both cases:

```
df
  subject scenario     NewVar
1       1       T1   personal
2       2       T3 impersonal
3       3       T3 impersonal
4       4       T2   personal
5       5       T2   personal
6       6       T4 impersonal
```

It can be also done using `dplyr` with `mutate()` and passing the `ifelse()` but you will have to install the package and learn about its functions. As you are beginner in `R` you could start first with `base R` and then upgrade to `dplyr` style.

Comment: Thank you! Your first recommendation worked like a charm.

Comment: @CarolinSchips Great! Continue learning to master `R` :) and if you have any pitfall related to some project let me know. I use to teach customized R programming sessions to solve key issues. If you feel interested at any point of time let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use logical subsetting to create new column.

```
df$personal_force <- c('impersonal', 'personal')[df$scenario %in% c('T1', 'T2') + 1]
df

#  subject scenario personal_force
#1       1       T1       personal
#2       2       T3     impersonal
#3       3       T3     impersonal
#4       4       T2       personal
#5       5       T2       personal
#6       6       T4     impersonal
```